# How print sql count on jsp?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

Root Cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

I have dao

```
 public List<Book> task3() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String sql = "SELECT books.genre, COUNT(*) AS counter FROM books  GROUP BY genre";

    SQLQuery query= session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.addEntity(Book.class);

    List<Book> authorList1   = query.list();

    return authorList1;
}
```

and controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task3", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String task3(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("task3", this.bookService.task3());

    return "task3";
}
```

How corect output this information on jsp?

I was tried like this but wrong :

```
 <c:if test="${!empty task3}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="120">name</th>
            <th width="120">genre</th>
            <th width="120">rating</th>
            <th width="120">published</th>

        </tr>


        <c:forEach items="${task3}" var="author">
            <tr>

                <td>${author.name}</td>
                <td>${author.genre}</td>
                <td>${author.rating}</td>
                <td>${author.published}</td>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>

enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: Please post more from the exception, to see why it failed. Try to replace ! with "not"

Comment: @Adina Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481) java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: Do you have imported taglib for c : <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> ?

Comment: @Adina yes I do

Comment: Ok, then the jsp engine is not configured correctly. Please paste your dependencies.

Comment: @Adina hibernate 4.3.5; spring(core, mvc) 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your service returns a list of `Object[]` not the `Author` entity ,

so you have to  call list after `query.AddEntity(...)` otherwise those line of code are useless ,

so your `taks2()` service method should be  as below :

```
public List<Author> task2() {

    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String sql = "SELECT sombra.author.*  FROM author, book_author WHERE author.id = book_author.`book_id` GROUP BY name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC";

    SQLQuery query= session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.addEntity(Author.class);
    query.addEntity(Book_author.class);

    List<Author> authorList1   = query.list();

    return authorList1;
}
```